How to maintain transcript output with Out-Null?
I want to log the execution of a script BUT I would like to Out-Null some lines so that they don’t appear on the CLI but still show up on the transcript. Is this possible?
I have no idea how to even attempt to circumvent Out-Null and have transcript ignore it.
Example:
Start-Transcript “Transcript location”
New-Item -ItemType File -Name "filename. txt | Out-Null
Stop-Transcript

So powershell shouldn’t say/show the file or that it was created but still can be found in the log file/area that’s specified in start transcript

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Based on MS documentation :

Start-transcript includes all command that the user types and all output that appears on the console
Out-null hides the output instead of sending it down the pipeline or displaying it

Having both at the same time is incompatible.
If further logging required I would advise you to investigate out-file to a dedicated logfile; Something like
New-Item -ItemType File -Name filename.txt | Out-File -FilePath .\some_path\file.log


You could enable the verbose option (output goes to stream 4).  Or just take the out-null away.
New-Item -ItemType File -Name filename.txt -verbose | Out-Null

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: 

